# How to make document ready execute multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, document-ready

I am loading a jsp using jquery. I have multiple buttons. On clicking, i am making a jquery call which loads a jsp in dialog box. I want the document ready function to be executed every time the jsp inside the jquery dialog box loads.
Step by step explanation :

This is the jquery function which loads ratingDialog.jsp in the dialog box each time rate is clicked.

```
function openRatingDialog() {
 var rateDialog = $('<div id="ratingloaderDiv"></div>')
 .load("ratingDialog.jsp").dialog({
     autoOpen: true,
     minHeight:275,
        width: 400,
        height: 350,  
     open: function( event, ui ) {
         $("#showDialogMessage").hide();
         $('#reviewArea').val('');
         $('#source').attr('checked', false);
         $('#destination').attr('checked', false);
         function openRatingDialog() {
 var rateDialog = $('<div id="ratingloaderDiv"></div>')
 .load("ratingDialog.jsp").dialog({
     autoOpen: true,
     minHeight:275,
        width: 400,
        height: 350,  
     open: function( event, ui ) {
         $(".rateCls").rating();
         $("#showDialogMessage").hide();
         $('#reviewArea').val('');
         $('#source').attr('checked', false);
         $('#destination').attr('checked', false);
         $("#submit").click(function(e) {
             $("#showDialogMessage").hide();
             var index = sessionStorage.getItem("history_index");
             alert(index);
             alert('submit clicked');
             alert(this.id);
             var rating = jQuery('#starVin .star:checked').val();
             var review = $("#reviewArea").val();
             var ratingDetails;
             if($('#source').is(":checked")&&   $('#destination').is(":checked")) {
                 ratingDetails = "overallRating";
             }
             else if ($('#source').is(":checked"))  
             {
               ratingDetails = $("#source").val();
             }
             else if ($('#destination').is(":checked"))
             {
               ratingDetails = $("#destination").val();
             }
             else
             {
                 ratingDetails = "vendorRating";
             }
              var xmlhttp;
                 $("#submit").prop('disabled',true);
                    var url="rate?index="+index+"&rating="+rating+"&review="+review+"&ratingDetails="+ratingDetails;
                    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                    {
                        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    }
                    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
                    {

                        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                        {
                            document.getElementById("showDialogMessage").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                            $("#showDialogMessage").show();
                            $("#submit").removeAttr('disabled');
                            if ($("#showDialogMessage:contains('Thanks')").length > 0) {
                                $("#"+index).hide();
                                $("#msg"+index).show();  
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);
                    xmlhttp.send();
            }); 

          }
      });
     } 
           }
       });
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
     var index ;
    $(".rate").on("click", function() {
     // Display the dialog
     openRatingDialog(); 
     index = this.id;
     });
```

This is ratingDialog.jsp

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/jquery.rating.css">
<div id="rateDialog" class="rateDialog" style="height:250px;width:500px;" title="Rating">
        <div id="showDialogMessage"></div>
        <p style="font-size:15px;color:black;margin:5px 0px 0px 10px;"><label>Rate your overall satisfaction:</label></p>
        <div id="starVin" style="display:block;">
         <input id="rateStar" type="radio" name="rating" value="1" class="rateCls star"/>
        <input id="rateStar" type="radio" name="rating" value="2" class="rateCls star" />
        <input id="rateStar" type="radio" name="rating" value="3" class="rateCls star"/>
        <input id="rateStar" type="radio" name="rating" value="4" class="rateCls star"/>
        <input id="rateStar" type="radio" name="rating" value="5" class="rateCls star"/>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <p style="font-size:15px;color:black;margin:5px 0px 0px 10px;"><label>Please provide your review: </label></p>
        <textarea id="reviewArea" name="reviewArea" rows="5"></textarea>
       <p style="font-size:15px;color:black;margin:5px 0px 0px 10px;"><label><input type="checkbox" id="source" value="source" name="source"> Rating specific to source pincode</label></p>
        <p style="font-size:15px;color:black;margin:5px 0px 0px 10px;"><label><input type="checkbox" id="destination" value="destination" name="destination"> Rating specific to destination pincode</label></p>
        <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" style="margin : 18px 0px 0px 93px;"/>
</div>
<script src = "js/jquery.rating.js"></script>
</script>
```

Each time ratingDialog loads i want its document.ready function to be executed. In my case, it is executing only once(for the first time it loads inside the dialog)

Comment: `ready` is an event. It occurs once (per page load). You can do nothing to make it occur more than once. However there's a thousand and one things you can do to make code execute multiple times in response to that event.

Comment: Have you read the "Script Execution" section, [here](https://api.jquery.com/load/)? It is relevant though it doesn't cover your exact usage case. Try hard-coding your `ratingloaderDiv` rather than re-creating it at each `.load()`.

Comment: Also, you can safely remove the `$(document).ready(function() {...})` wrapper from the loaded content as there's no chance it will ever run before the page's `ready` event.

Comment: The problem is that i am trying to put rating stars in the dialog box. For the first time the radio buttons are converting into the stars. But if we click on rate button again the radio buttons are not converting into stars. The radio button appears for a while and then disappears. I am using this plugin http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/

Comment: I have identified the problem. Since the name of radio buttons are same it is placing the total stars in first dialog box. So now the problem is reduced to giving different names to radio button each time the jsp loads. I have added this question as separate. Please do help. I am stuck from past 2-3 hrs on this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29575594/use-jstl-global-variable-as-id-in-jsp

Comment: I'll have a look ...

Comment: Use a `form` element. Radio buttons of the same `name` are linked on a per-form basis so as long as each instance of `rateDialog` is a 'form` they wont cross-talk. Also, ID's should be unique so I recommend: `<form class="rateDialog" style="height:250px;width:500px;" title="Rating">` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29575594/use-jstl-global-variable-as-id-in-jsp/29576148#29576148

Comment: You could consider using a CSS-only star-ratings control. Then you would have a ratings script to initialise at all. http://codepen.io/moob/pen/LEKrLg

Comment: your last edit should be a new question

Comment: @DelightedD0D     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29577728/submit-button-is-not-working-in-dialog  Here is my new question Sir

Comment: @DelightedD0D Sir Can u please look into this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29600009/jquery-code-not-working-without-breakpoint We together worked out this code one day back. I am stuck with this weird issue from past few hours. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about moving your document ready code to your dialog callback?

```
var rateDialog;
$('<div id="ratingloaderDiv"></div>')
    .load("ratingDialog.jsp", function() {
        rateDialog = $(this).dialog({
            autoOpen: true,
            minHeight:275,
            width: 400,
            height: 350,  
            open: function( event, ui ) {
                $("#showDialogMessage").hide();
                $('#reviewArea').val('');
                $('#source').attr('checked', false);
                $('#destination').attr('checked', false);

                // Document ready
                $(".rateStar").show();
                $(".rateCls").rating();
                alert('hi'); 
            }
        });
    });
```

Moving the dialog call to your load callback also ensures it doesn't run until your file is retrieved.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply use an iFrame in your dialog like the below.

**Also, you will want to keep a reference to your dialog and destroy it when it is closed, otherwise you will be adding it to your page over and over again**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var rateDialog;
    function openRatingDialog() {
        rateDialog = $('<div id="ratingloaderDiv"><iframe id="ratingIframe" src="ratingDialog.html" width="200" height="200" frameborder="0" onload="parent.ratingsLoaded();"></iframe></div>')
            .dialog({
            autoOpen: true,
            minHeight: 275,
            width: 400,
            height: 350,
            open: function (event, ui) {
            },
            close: function (event, ui) {
                rateDialog.dialog('destroy').remove();
            }
        });
    }
    $(".rate").on("click", function () {
        // Display the dialog
        openRatingDialog();
    });
});
var curIndex=0;
function ratingsLoaded(){
            var name = 'rating'+curIndex
            var iframe = $('#ratingIframe').contents();
            iframe.find("#showDialogMessage").hide();
            iframe.find('#reviewArea').val('');
            iframe.find('#source').attr('checked', false);
            iframe.find('#destination').attr('checked', false);
            iframe.find('.rateCls').attr('name', name);
            curIndex++;

}
```

### Here is a [working example](http://dodsoftware.com/sotests/doc-ready/rating.html)

Comment: Yeah sir. I have hooked the two lines to the open callback of dialog box. Now am stuck with different issue. I have posted it as separate question. Please help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29575594/use-jstl-global-variable-as-id-in-jsp

Comment: @user3681970 see my edit above and the updated example page. They will address both questions

Comment: An iFrame should not be necessary - '.load()' should be perfectly adequate - just needs coding correctly. Also, with an appropriate `#showDialogMessage: {display:none}` directive in *dist/jquery.rating.css*, `ratingsLoaded()` can be dispensed with completely. And as I understand it, the idea to rename the `.rateCls` buttons was a workaround for the badly coded `.load()`, and will be overcome when the dialog is properly replaced at each reload - therefore should also be unnecessary.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 you're right, josh and I just worked out that the issue in my test page was due to my loading jquery again in the page being loaded

Comment: @user3681970 Josh's answer below is actually more suited to the question, but be sure to remove the dialog so you're not adding it repeatedly

Comment: @DelightedD0D Sir in ratingDialog.jsp (which is loaded in dialog box on clicking rate icon), i have a submit button. On clicking the submit every time i want to make ajax call. As told, i wrote ('#submit').click function in the dialog callback. But it is not working. Please help sir.

Comment: I am not using the iframe sir. I am using thejosh's solution but submit.click is not working in the dialog callback. Please see the edited code and guide me