# use jstl global variable as id in JSP

Tags: jquery, jsp, jstl

I have a jsp. This jsp is loaded several times using jquery.load. I have some codes in jquery

```
<input type="radio" name="rating" value="1" class="rateCls star"/>
        <input  type="radio" name="rating" value="2" class="rateCls star" />
        <input  type="radio" name="rating" value="3" class="rateCls star"/>
        <input  type="radio" name="rating" value="4" class="rateCls star"/>
        <input  type="radio" name="rating" value="5" class="rateCls star"/>
```

I want the name of input radio to be changed each time it loads. Like for the first time it loads the name may be say "rating-0" for the second time it loads the name should be changed to "rating-1" and so on.
I think of creating global variable and increment it something like this but it is not working.

```
<%!int index=1;%>
  <index+=1;>
  <input type="radio" name="rating+${index}" value="1" class="rateCls star"/>
        <input  type="radio" name="rating" value="2" class="rateCls star" />
        <input  type="radio" name="rating" value="3" class="rateCls star"/>
        <input  type="radio" name="rating" value="4" class="rateCls star"/>
        <input  type="radio" name="rating" value="5" class="rateCls star"/>
```

I do not know how to use jstl global variable as id in jsp.

Comment: Answer posted on your previous question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29574854/how-to-make-document-ready-execute-multiple-times/29575702#29575702

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `form` element. Radio buttons of the same `name` are linked on a per-form basis so as long as each instance of these rating group is wrapped in its own `form` they wont cross-talk and so you'll avoid the need to give each group of radio buttons a unique `name`.

> Radio buttons that have the same value for the name attribute are in the same "radio button group"; only one radio button in a group can be selected at one time.
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input

[Here's an example jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v2jtdsxg/) using the HTML markup from [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29574854/how-to-make-document-ready-execute-multiple-times). The 2 forms are the exactly the same but the radios don't conflict.