# submit button is not working in dialog

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, jquery-callback

I am loading a separate JSP using jquery in a dialog box. Dialog box has a button submit. I want to make ajax call on clicking submit. I am including submit.click on the dialog callback function but it is not working. Here is the step by step code.

First Jquery code to load JSP :

```
function openRatingDialog() {
 var rateDialog = $('<div id="ratingloaderDiv"></div>')
 .load("ratingDialog.jsp").dialog({
     autoOpen: true,
     minHeight:275,
        width: 400,
        height: 350,  
     open: function( event, ui ) {
         $(".rateCls").rating();
         $("#showDialogMessage").hide();
         $('#reviewArea').val('');
         $('#source').attr('checked', false);
         $('#destination').attr('checked', false);
         $("#submit").click(function(e) {
             $("#showDialogMessage").hide();
             var index = sessionStorage.getItem("history_index");
             alert(index);
             alert('submit clicked');
             alert(this.id);
             var rating = jQuery('#starVin .star:checked').val();
             var review = $("#reviewArea").val();
             var ratingDetails;
             if($('#source').is(":checked")&& $('#destination').is(":checked")) {
                 ratingDetails = "overallRating";
             }
             else if ($('#source').is(":checked"))  
             {
               ratingDetails = $("#source").val();
             }
             else if ($('#destination').is(":checked"))
             {
               ratingDetails = $("#destination").val();
             }
             else
             {
                 ratingDetails = "vendorRating";
             }
              var xmlhttp;
                 $("#submit").prop('disabled',true);
                    var url="rate?index="+index+"&rating="+rating+"&review="+review+"&ratingDetails="+ratingDetails;
                    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                    {
                        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    }
                    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
                    {

                        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                        {
                            document.getElementById("showDialogMessage").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                            $("#showDialogMessage").show();
                            $("#submit").removeAttr('disabled');
                            if ($("#showDialogMessage:contains('Thanks')").length > 0) {
                                $("#"+index).hide();
                                $("#msg"+index).show();  
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);
                    xmlhttp.send();
             }); 

       }
     });
     }
   $(document).ready(function() {
 $(".rate").on("click", function() {
     // Display the dialog
     var index = this.id;
     sessionStorage.setItem("history_index", index);
     openRatingDialog(); 
     });
});
```

Here is the ratingdialog.jsp which is loaded into the dialog box

```
<form id="rateDialog" class="rateDialog" style="height:250px;width:500px;" title="Rating">
        <div id="showDialogMessage"></div>
        <p style="font-size:15px;color:black;margin:5px 0px 0px 10px;"><label>Rate your overall satisfaction:</label></p>
        <div id="starVin" style="display:block;">
        <input id="rateStars" type="radio"  value="1" class="rateCls star"/>
        <input id="rateStars" type="radio"  value="2" class="rateCls star" />
        <input id="rateStars" type="radio"  value="3" class="rateCls star"/>
        <input id="rateStars"  type="radio"  value="4" class="rateCls star"/>
        <input id="rateStars" type="radio"  value="5" class="rateCls star"/>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <p style="font-size:15px;color:black;margin:5px 0px 0px 10px;"><label>Please provide your review: </label></p>
        <textarea id="reviewArea" name="reviewArea" rows="5"></textarea>
       <p style="font-size:15px;color:black;margin:5px 0px 0px 10px;"><label><input type="checkbox" id="source" value="source" name="source"> Rating specific to source pincode</label></p>
        <p style="font-size:15px;color:black;margin:5px 0px 0px 10px;"><label><input type="checkbox" id="destination" value="destination" name="destination"> Rating specific to destination pincode</label></p>
        <input id="submit" type="button" value="Submit" style="margin : 18px 0px 0px 93px;"/>
```

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: The code to submit the ajax on click seems fine. The only issue I can see arising is if you have multiple dialog boxes open with the same submit buttons of the same ID. Your event will always only bind to the first one. In that case, I'd suggest generating some sort of a random variable specific to each dialog to attach to your element IDs, class names, etc. If your problem is your submit button is only submitting on the first dialog box, I'd be glad to post some example code to give you an idea.

Comment: @JoshBjelovuk        Thank you very much Sir. As i am beginner to this, can you please give some sample code to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give something like this a try:

```
var dialogId = 0; // Global variable

function openRatingDialog() {
    var id = dialogId++;
    var rateDialog = $('<div id="ratingloaderDiv"></div>')
    .load("ratingDialog.jsp?id="+ id).dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        minHeight:275,
        width: 400,
        height: 350,  
        open: function( event, ui ) {
            $(".rateCls"+ id).rating();
            $("#showDialogMessage"+ id).hide();
            $('#reviewArea'+ id).val('');
            $('#source'+ id).attr('checked', false);
            $('#destination'+ id).attr('checked', false);
            $("#submit"+ id).click(function(e) {
            [...]
```

JSP File:

```
<% String id = request.getParameter("id"); %>

<form id="rateDialog<%=id%>" class="rateDialog<%=id%>" style="height:250px;width:500px;" title="Rating">
    <div id="showDialogMessage<%=id%>"></div>
    <p style="font-size:15px;color:black;margin:5px 0px 0px 10px;"><label>Rate your overall satisfaction:</label></p>
    <div id="starVin<%=id%>" style="display:block;">
    <input id="rateStars<%=id%>" type="radio" value="1" class="rateCls<%=id%> star<%=id%>"/>
    <input id="rateStars<%=id%>" type="radio" value="2" class="rateCls<%=id%> star<%=id%>" />
    <input id="rateStars<%=id%>" type="radio" value="3" class="rateCls<%=id%> star<%=id%>"/>
    <input id="rateStars<%=id%>" type="radio" value="4" class="rateCls<%=id%> star<%=id%>"/>
    <input id="rateStars<%=id%>" type="radio" value="5" class="rateCls<%=id%> star<%=id%>"/>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <p style="font-size:15px;color:black;margin:5px 0px 0px 10px;"><label>Please provide your review: </label></p>
    <textarea id="reviewArea<%=id%>" name="reviewArea" rows="5"></textarea>
    <p style="font-size:15px;color:black;margin:5px 0px 0px 10px;"><label><input type="checkbox" id="source<%=id%>" value="source" name="source"> Rating specific to source pincode</label></p>
    <p style="font-size:15px;color:black;margin:5px 0px 0px 10px;"><label><input type="checkbox" id="destination<%=id%>" value="destination" name="destination"> Rating specific to destination pincode</label></p>
    <input id="submit<%=id%>" type="button" value="Submit" style="margin : 18px 0px 0px 93px;"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Sir I copied the same code. But on clicking the submit button it is not making any ajax call. :( :(

Comment: Sorry, slight oversight. I've updated the first part.

Comment: Sir i tried the updated one. But still the same issue. It is not firing the ajax call :'( :(

Comment: Not even the first time? Does the html source line up with what you have in your JSP, correct IDs, etc.? Make sure the submit click event is firing, put a breakpoint in it. Put another breakpoint inside of your `onreadystatechange` event. Gotta narrow down the issues.

Comment: no sir.. it is not firing even for the first time. And that radio buttons are not converting into stars also.  :( It is getting the correct Id and id is incrementing also every time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75006/discussion-between-josh-bjelovuk-and-user3681970).

Comment: Sir..thank you so much it worked. :-) thanks for ur time n help..I was doing some typo.. My bad..it is firing Ajax call everytime. :-)